# Differentiate between child classes from a parent class object?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

I am working on 2 hierarchies that are something similar to below -

Hierarchy 1:

```
public class Content
{
}

public class Text : Content
{
}

public class Image : Content
{
}
```

Hierarchy 2:

```
public class ContentProperties
{
}

public class TextProperties : ContentProperties
{
}

public class ImageProperties : ContentProperties
{
}
```

Now I want to achieve 2 behaviors :

First is, I want a Property of ContentProperties in Content so that I can generalize it for all the Child classes of Content. I can then assign them independently in child classes as per required child type.

Something like this.

```
public class Content
{
    public ContentProperties Properties {get;set;}
}

public class Text : Content
{
    public Text()
    {
        this.Properties = new TextProperties();
    }
}
```

... and so on for other child classes.

Second is, I want to restrict one type of child class to have only its corresponding type of properties to be assigned to.

e.g

```
Text text = new Text();
text.Properties = new ImageProperties(); //This should give an error - should not be possible.
```

I can achieve the second behavior by keeping individual properties in individual child classes but that would contradict my first behavior. Also, I don't want to keep redundant data by creating two separate objects. I can achieve something similar using check-in Property setter or use setter methods, however, it wouldn't be exact behavior.

Can anyone suggest how I can achieve the above behaviors?

Sorry for an incorrectly phrased title if it caused any misunderstanding.

Comment: You could make the Properties type a generic type of your content class, and then base your type on the generic parameter

Comment: @Icepickle That's a good way towards the problem, however won't that cause problems if I have a List of Contents that might be either Text or Image and I want to only update ContentProperties members of those objects.

Comment: Not really, you would always have the `if (item is Text textContentItem)` construction when you are looping, so you would always know exactly what you would have ;)

Comment: @Icepickle, That's right. Correct me if I am wrong, but won't your implementation remove the entire purpose of ContentProperties hierarchy ?

Comment: I don't completely understand what you mean with removing the purpose, isn't your purpose to have a typesafe way to implement a generic member on your base classes? At some point you would have to decide how to handle them. I think my biggest problem with the current idea would be that I have a setter for the properties, I would go for an autoproperty that gets set once. But if doing it in the proposed way seems bad for you at the moment, then you need to provide more info what exactly is bugging you? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use generics with [constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters):

```
public class Content<T> where T : ContentProperties 
{
    public T Properties {get;set;}
}

public class Text : Content<TextProperties>
{
}

public class Image : Content<ImageProperties>
{
}
```

I edit the answer - You don't have to define the properties again in the subclass....

The property "Properties" in the subclasses will be of types `TextProperties`and `ImageProperties`.

Thanks for your comments

Comment: @JasmeetsinghBansal Yes it will. Properties should be declared virtual and overridden in the derived classes where the getter and setter access TextProperties and ImageProperties, respectively. This way you can access the base properties from the Properties property and when you want to access the text or image-specific ones you can access TextProperties and ImageProperties. All the while there is only one properties instance.

Comment: @OfirWinegarten Just a doubt.Won't this implementation cause problems if I have a List of Contents that might be either Text or Image and I want to only update ContentProperties members of those objects.

Comment: No, You can always do that. `List<ContentProperties>` can store both of the subclasses. a simple foreach will give you `ContentProperties`, and you can always choose to get only a specific type by using `OfType`